# Linux mint. Letters missing from title bar

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I am running Linux Mint with the [image: cinnamon] desktop. In my title bar, a few letters are missing

What can I do to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/ that's the place to go.

Comment: I've asked there 2 hours ago. I though you guys might be more active / asking in two places does no harm, as I can post the solution there / here when I discover it.

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=257494

Comment: Mint issues are hyper specific to Mint, and since Mint makes cinnamon if I remember right, that's the right place to ask. Debian or Ubuntu knowledge do not reliably map to Mint issues, unfortunately, so really you're just looking for Mint users in general that might know the issue. That's a hyper specific bug, could be cinnamon, well it almost certainly is cinnamon, since that's the window component that's managed by the display manager. It's a bug, so you should report it upstream to the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's obviously a bug in Cinnamon, it creates the Window wrappers, the parts surrounding in this case the web page, that is. Bugs should be reported to the authors of the software in question, in this case, Cinnamon, which is I believe a Mint run project, so you should report it either to Mint bug trackers, or go upstream a bit further and report it to Cinnamon bug trackers.

The issue is in the window title bar, which is created by the window manager, Cinnamon in this case. At least, that's normally the case.

It could maybe also be a bug in the theming method, but I don't know what Cinnamon does with themes. Either way, it's a bug. For software authors to be able to find and fix the bug, it's immensely helpful if they can reproduce it, so you want to give them as much information as possible about where it occurs. Does it, for example, occur on other software running in windows on Cinnamon? Or just browsers? If just browsers, does it happen with Chrome, with Firefox? Or just one of those?

If you use themes, switch themes, and verify that the bug remains when you switch. This will be important information for the bug handlers, as will be the specific release version of Cinnamon you are running.

Generally you want to start at the distro level because the project level is often many releases ahead of the version you are running, since Mint is a frozen pool distribution, it's software versions will only be as of the time of the pool freeze.

Given there are no other corruptions, it seems unlikely that it's an Xorg or video driver issue, those would generally manifest in a more generalized way.

As a software author, I can assure you that reporting bugs on stackexchange does exactly nothing to help correct the bugs. When reporting the bug, you may be asked to provide additional information. This is critical to resolving the bug.

Here's the relevant bug tracker: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues

If they have a search feature, make sure you search first, and also look through the active issue list to make sure it's not there already, if it is, add your specifics to the issue report, don't create a new one.

Comment: According to someone on the bug page, it happens also on other distros and might not be mint and cinnamon specific. https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1287612

Comment: Umm, the bug report explicitly says it's cinnamon specific. So you can in fact exclude mint, which is good, and just report it, or add data to, the Cinnamon bug report in that case. If you see my answer, my assumption was that it is a cinnamon bug, because that's what is writing that data to the page. Critical to collect data on is Cinnamon versions etc, so make sure to provide all that data to the bug thread.

Comment: I didn't create the thread. I just found it while trying to create my own.

Comment: I know, I'm simply noting that in fact the bug was specifically mentioned as cinnamon specific, not distro related. That's important. Us talking further will do nothing to help resolve this issue so you'll want to go to the cinnamon bug tracker, I added the link

Comment: Ok. Is there a cinnamon repository I can report it on?

Comment: There are almost always for all software projects bug trackers, because that's how we find and fix bugs, if people can't report them, it's difficult for software authors to handle and correct the issues they have not themselves experienced. Google: [project name] bug tracker OR issue reports. Since my answer proved correct, feel free to accept it.